# What is the correct way to declare a property of type function_handle in an abstract class in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, oop, interface, function-handle

I'm trying to create an interface that other classes in MATLAB will inherit. This interface has a property that holds a function_handle value. The problem I'm running into is that, upon instantiating a concrete class that inherits from this class, I get the message: `Error defining property 'MyFuncHandle' of class 'IMyInterfaceClass'. Unable to construct default object of class function_handle.`

The interface class looks something like this:

```
classdef (Abstract) IMyInterfaceClass < handle
    properties (Abstract)
        MyFuncHandle(1,1) function_handle
    end

    methods (Abstract, Access = public)
        % Some abstract methods declared here
    end
end
```

With another class inheriting the interface like this:

```
classdef (Abstract) MyClassThatInheritsTheInterface < IMyInterfaceClass & SomeOtherAbstractClass
    properties
        MyFuncHandle
    end

    methods (Abstract)
        % Some abstract methods declared here
    end

    methods
        function this = MyClassThatInheritsTheInterface()
            this@SomeOtherAbstractClass();
        end

        % Some concrete methods declared here
    end
end
```

And, ultimately, a concrete subclass that inherits from `MyClassThatInheritsTheInterface`.

I've tried changing the property declaration in `IMyInterfaceClass` to:

```
    properties (Abstract)
        MyFuncHandle(1,1) function_handle = function_handle.empty
    end
```

But, that doesn't work. I've also tried just setting it to a default value like this:

```
    properties (Abstract)
        MyFuncHandle(1,1) function_handle = @ode15s
    end
```

That doesn't work either.

Is there any way to get this to work, while keeping the type-checking on `MyFuncHandle` in `IMyInterfaceClass`? Obviously, getting rid of the type check and leaving it as a duck-typed property would eliminate the error but would not ensure that the value in the property is a function_handle.

Comment: Strangely, if I change the type to double instead of function_handle, leaving the property declared abstract in the interface, I do not get an error. It's something about function_handle, specifically, that causes this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can distil the example down a bit to fix this issue

**Abstract super class**

```
classdef (Abstract) IMyInterfaceClass < handle
    properties 
        MyFuncHandle(1,1) function_handle = @(varargin) disp([])
    end
    methods (Abstract, Access = public)
        % Some abstract methods declared here
    end
end
```

**Concrete class** which inherits the abstract class

```
classdef MyClassThatInheritsTheInterface < IMyInterfaceClass
    properties
        % Subclass properties
    end
    methods
        function this = MyClassThatInheritsTheInterface()
            this@IMyInterfaceClass();
        end
        % Some concrete methods declared here
    end
end
```

These are pretty much lifted from your example, except I've skipped the 2nd layer of abstraction and just used one abstract superclass. The following points should still be applicable.

Note that `MyFuncHandle` should only be specified in the abstract super class.

Also `function_handle.empty` is, as you might expect, empty. However, you want a 1x1 function handle per your property specification. The simplest "do-nothing" function I know of which satisfies this is `@(varargin) disp([])` which accepts any inputs and displays nothing. You could of course use something which instead throws an error if it's not been overwritten

```
@(varargin) error( 'MyFuncHandle has not been defined' );
```

Now you can do `a = MyClassThatInheritsTheInterface();` and you will see that `a.MyFuncHandle` is correctly initialised.

Perhaps the key here is that at no point does this try to class something as both an `Abstract` property, whilst also giving it a value which is not consistent with it being abstract.

Comment: My favourite do-nothing function is spelled `@()[]`

Comment: @Edric but if `f = @()[]` then `f(1)` (or any other inputs) throws an error, and `f()` displays `ans = []`. So there is no way to use `f` where it literally does nothing, it always does _something_ by that definition. Whereas `f = @(varargin) disp([]);` will accept any inputs (or none) and not display or affect anything

Comment: Although this answer makes the error go away, it also changes the semantics slightly by making the property concrete instead of abstract in the interface. The original semantics were, "This interface requires a property having this name and data type. Users of the interface must implement such a property." The semantics of your solution are, "This interface implements a property of this name and data type. Users of the interface inherit this concrete property." Probably not an important difference in this case, but a difference nonetheless.

Comment: @Wolfie fair point. I was thinking mostly about a function that would never be executed, but had to exist.

Comment: Slightly longer, but `@(varargin) eval('return')` makes the "do nothing" intention clearer, I think. With `disp([])`, someone reading the code later might question if there was actually supposed to be some text displayed and somebody forgot to implement that.

Comment: Oof but `eval` feels icky, I'd rather issue a warning / error. I see your point about the abstraction but don't have a simple solution

Comment: Another possibility is to create a function named `donothing` with `varargin` for its input where the function body consists solely of a `return` statement. The `eval` was only necessary because `@(varargin) return` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use a validation function rather than a class/size constraint. I realise it doesn't feel quite as satisfactory, but it can be a useful approach. In this case

```
properties
    SomeFcn {mustBeA(SomeFcn, "function_handle")}
end
```